# Existence of trace operator in$ W^{s,p} (D)$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces, trace-map

Let $D$ be a smooth, bounded domain. $W^{s,p} (D)$ denotes the fractional Sobolev space defined as in [Hitchhiker's Guide to Fractional Sobolev Space](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345). Assume that $s>\frac{1}{p}$. I want to show that there exists an continuous linear transformation $T:W^{s, p} (D) \to L^p(\partial D) $ such that Tu=u on $\partial D$ whenever $u$ is continuous.

There are books/papers where the case $p=2$ is taken care of but I want a proof in this setup. Some authors have cited [Théorèmesdetraceetd’interpolation](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASNSP_1959_3_13_4_389_0) but I could figure out where it is done.

Also, may be for the problem I posed, the proof will become much simpler because I only want to show that the trace operator is continuous ant the codomain is Lebesgue space not a Sobolev space.

Comment: I found the result in Françoise and Gilbert Demengel's book "Functional Spaces for the Theory of Elliptic Partial Differential Equations" Chapter 4. Doesn't look easy to streamline the proof